# Css / hover efect / controling behavior of another class with different class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am new on css. I am trying to built a calculator. What I am trying to do is that
when I click a button on the calculator, a menu (sin, cos, tan, cot) must show up. I have no idea if it is possible. I searched it but I am having hard time to find it. Can you help ? I explained below in detail.

Here is some of html...

```
    <div class="calculator">
            <div class="screen">536,125</div>
            <div class="above-numbers">
                <div>√</div>
                <div>Π</div>
                <div>^</div>
                <div>!</div>
                <div class="show-more">V</div>  // When I hover over this div, page must render the div below but 
it should not render it if I am not hovering over it
                <div class="tr-menu">
                    <div>sin</div>
                    <div>cos</div>
                    <div>tan</div>
                    <div>cot</div>
                    <div>cosec</div>
                    <div>sec</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am triyng to control class="tr-menu" div  from class="show-more" div.

Here is some of my css

```
.above-numbers{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.above-numbers div{
    border: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #282a2d;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.show-more{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.show-more:hover{
    height: 100px;

}
```

[image]

[image]

when I hover over 'V' a menu must show up and that menu must contain sin cos tan ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get hover working by changing css for this :

```
            .tr-menu{
            display:none;
        }

        .show-more:hover + div {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            height: 100px;

        }
```

It should get you started. See here for example : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/display-div-element-on-hovering-over-a-tag-using-css/

Oh, and maybe you should update your title for something more specific since you were looking for a CSS hover.